# How do I work with grids when I need padding and margin?

Tags: css, grid, grid-system

I've stayed clear of using any kind of grid systems because I always mess it up with padding and margin.

Let's sat my grids are at 90px and I have this code:

```
//HTML
<div class="col1">
 <div class="content">
   Hello world
 </div>
</div>

//CSS
.col1 { width: 90px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: #444; }
.content { margin: 20px; color: #fff; background-color: #0087d5; width: 100%; }
```

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xtFVX/1/).

How can I work with grids, make sure the grid remains 90px width, while having inside ´div´ at 100% width with 20px padding / margin?

I know there are many grid systems out there and I've tested a few, but I must be "attacking" this the wrong way because my grids always expands when I start using padding to get some space.

Comment: There are spaces between the grids themselves, so you don't need to worry about margins and padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be applying `box-sizing`, which accounts for padding when computing the width (i.e. `90px` + `10px` for padding, will apply the padding *inwards*, rather than creating a *total width* of `110px`. If you want to be extra safe, add this to your reset or normalise stylesheet:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

For older versions of Safari & Firefox:

```
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box }
```

Using the wildcard selector allows the `box-sizing` property to be applied to *all elements*. I know this is included in some grid systems out there, e.g. [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com).

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about that. I'll give it a go :)